# JSON Iteration - My JSON object is being treated as a string literal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This is probably a super easy question but I'm banging my head on it for some reason.

Here is the jQuery I have

```
$(function() {
    $.get(urlGetContainerNumbers, function(data) {
        console.log(data);

        for (var idx = 0; idx < data.length; idx++) {
            var containerNo = data[idx];
            console.log(containerNo);
        }
    });
});
```

This is what is produced in firebug

[image: JSON Iteration]

I am expecting that when iterating through `data` I would get 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, etc.

What am I overlooking? It seems as though the for loop isn't treating `data` as a json object, but rather a string literal...

Comment: `data = eval("( " + data + ")");`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Methinks you mean `$.getJSON` rather than `$.get`.

Answer (score 5):

Use 'json' as 4th parameter of function $.get

```
$.get(url, params, callback, 'json');
```

Answer (score 4):

Call jQuery.getJSON() instead of the more generic jQuery.get().