# Can't access a property in a json object returned

Tags: ajax, json, object, properties, encode

I get a response from an ajax request and store request.responseText in a variable called requestData. *requestData* data contains a json object pass by php using json_encode().

See a couple of log I made bellow.

```
requestData : {"status":"ok","to":"","html":"<option value=\"Huberdeau\">Huberdeau<\/option><option value=\"Bo\u00eeleau\">Bo\u00eeleau<\/option><option value=\"Br\u00e9beuf\">Br\u00e9beuf<\/option><option value=\"Saint-R\u00e9mi-d'Amherst\">Saint-R\u00e9mi-d'Amherst<\/option><option value=\"Harrington\">Harrington<\/option>","message":"old"}
```

My probleme is that I can't access the variable status. None of the following calls get the value properly.

```
requestData[status] : undefined
requestData.status : undefined
requestData['status'] : undefined
requestData[0]['status'] : undefined
```

And when I tried to dump my variable by a for log it treated it like string.

```
dump_var :
0:{
1:"
2:s
3:t
4:a
5:t
6:u
7:s
8:"
9::
```

Comment: I don't think you're assigning the JSON response properly. Show your AJAX request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the trick in a comment on an other question. I post it here anyway cause it's a bit difficult to notice in the [original discussion](http://%28https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488067/json-iteration-my-json-object-is-being-treated-as-a-string-literal%29).

```
var requestData = request['responseText'];
var jsonData = eval("( " + requestData + ")");
```

Answer (score 1):

in jQuery

instead of $.get

use $.getJSON

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data){
     alert(data.someField);
});
```

then you don't need to do eval !!